# Suppress the "unused" warning for a method, but not the variables within it

Tags: java, suppress-warnings

As the title asks, how do I suppress the warning for just the method? Is this possible?

A little background: I'm using a JavaScript bridge and it hooks into these methods, so I'd like to suppress this warning. What I would like to avoid is the annotation preventing warnings for unused variables within the method. I'm currently just using the `@SuppressWarnings("unused")` before the method declaration, but this suppresses everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no way to scope SurpressWarning to the method declaration only.

This leaves you with these possibilities:

- Increase the visibility of the method to package or protected. Slightly increasing visibility has the added benefit that it becomes available to unit tests.
- Create a dummy method which has call to the unused methods. (This feels really ugly).

Answer (score 3):

In eclipse, If we set the following

> Preferences -> Java -> Error/Warnings -> Unnecessary code -> Local
>   variable is never read ==> Error

then, even when the @SuppressWarnings("unused") is applied on the method it only suppresses unused method warning. The unused variable is shown as an Error.

(I know, you wanted them to be 'warnings' but all I can come up with are 'errors' !)